# How do I show a DIalog Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, showdialog

Hi I wanted to know how I could show a dialog on screen when the user clicks on a button;

java file;

```
public class Example extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.exampleButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("Jomin","sdsd");
                ExampleDialogFragment CallUs = new ExampleDialogFragment();
                CallUs.getDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this the ExampleDialogFragment java file;

```
public class ExampleDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(false);      builder.setTitle(R.string.LogOutTitle).setMessage(R.string.LogOutMessage).setPositiveButton(R.string.LogOutPositive,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:0845 3000 116");
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

So can someone tell me how I would be able to show this dialog when the user clicks on button with the ID - exampleButton.

Comment: I have tried using ;  CallUs.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"call"); but getting an error saying can't resolve method 'getsupportfragmentmanager'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
callUs.show(getFragmentManager(), "SOME_TAG");
```

And I think you have to switch your activity to FragmentActivity and repalce getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager() as your DialogFragment extends version from Support Library

Comment: I have just tried that getting an error saying "cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)'"

Comment: I didn't read everything you said, specially the bit where you mentioned about extending it from Fragment Activity  and replacing it with getsupportfragment manager

Answer (score 1):

This is a good guide: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
// ...

public class FragmentDialogDemo extends FragmentActivity implements EditNameDialogListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    showEditDialog();
}

private void showEditDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
    editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to this but not helping me to fix it